# How to make a parser of PLY in Godot: Triangle Fan

Tags: 3d, mesh, godot, gdscript

I've been creating a tool for shading 3D models in Godot but I need to be able to translate the PLY format to SurfaceTool in Godot. PLY format has a header that explains what is the structure and then gives the data. Here's an example of a cube:

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
comment made by Greg Turk
comment this file is a cube
element vertex 8
property float x
property float y
property float z
element face 6
property list uchar int vertex_index
end_header
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 1
0 1 0
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 1
1 1 0
4 0 1 2 3
4 7 6 5 4
4 0 4 5 1
4 1 5 6 2
4 2 6 7 3
4 3 7 4 0
```

I have put in diferrent arrays the vertex and the faces info in header. I've created the mesh like this:

```
var meshBuilder = SurfaceTool.new()
meshBuilder.begin(Mesh.PRIMITIVE_TRIANGLE_FAN)
```

I have added the vertex like this:

```
for i in range(vertex_count):
                    meshBuilder.add_normal(Vector3.UP)
                    meshBuilder.add_vertex(Vector3(float(data[0]),
                                        float(data[1]),
                                        float(data[2])))
                    line = loadedFile.get_line()
                    if line == "":
                        break
                    data = line.split(" ")
```

But I do not know how to add the faces. It is a triangle fan, where the first face 4 0 1 2 3 is 4 vertex, composed of the triangles 0,1,2 and 0,2,3 and not 0,1,2 and 1,2,3. That's the order of the used vertex.

Maybe I am supposed to add the vertex in that exact order that the face says but I do not know how to use add_uv because I have been told to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, do not add the vertex to the `SurfaceTool` directly. You are going to store the vertex in an array, and then add them according to the faces you read from the file.

Second, in the PLY format each *face* is a Triangle Fan. *The whole is not a Triangle Fan.* Furthermore, `SurfaceTool` will not let you create multiple triangle fans at once (a second call to `begin` internally calls `clear`). Thus, we need to commit each Triangle Fan as we create them.

*And, by the way, there is no UV (texture coordinates) in your example.*

---

Let us start by storing the vertex into an array (assuming you just read "end_header"):

```
var vertex_array:Array = []
for vertex_index in vertex_count:
    line = loadedFile.get_line()
    data = line.split(" ")
    var vertex := Vector3(float(data[0]), float(data[1]), float(data[2]))
    vertex_array.append(vertex)
```

Then we need to read the faces:

```
var mesh := ArrayMesh.new()
var mesh_builder := SurfaceTool.new()

for face_index in faces_count:
    line = loadedFile.get_line()
    data = line.split(" ")

    mesh_builder.begin(Mesh.PRIMITIVE_TRIANGLE_FAN)

    for face_vertex_index in range(1, data.size()):
        mesh_builder.add_vertex(vertex_array[int(data[face_vertex_index])])

    mesh_builder.commit(mesh)
```

Note that I did forgo processing the number of vertex in the face (`data[0]`). Instead I skip it by using `range(1, data.size())` (the range would start at `0` instead of `1` if we included it). The other values in `data` are the indexes of the array where we stored the vertex.

So `4 0 1 2 3` means I need to go take the vertex from that array which are at position `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3` (As I said, I did forgo processing the `4`).

---

Setting normals requires extra work. We need to process each triangle separately (not each triangle fan), and compute the normal.

*The normal is vector perpendicular to the triangle, we can compute by doing a cross product of the differences of the vertex. Which means we need the set of vertex that make each triangle, to compute their normals.*

If we are going to process each triangle separately, we might as well use `PRIMITIVE_TRIANGLES` and use `generate_normals` (which only works when we are using `PRIMITIVE_TRIANGLES`):

```
var mesh := ArrayMesh.new()
var mesh_builder := SurfaceTool.new()

for face_index in faces_count:
    line = loadedFile.get_line()
    data = line.split(" ")

    mesh_builder.begin(Mesh.PRIMITIVE_TRIANGLES)

    for triangle_index in range(2, data.size() - 1):
        mesh_builder.add_vertex(vertex_array[int(data[1])])
        mesh_builder.add_vertex(vertex_array[int(data[triangle_index])])
        mesh_builder.add_vertex(vertex_array[int(data[triangle_index + 1])])

    surface_tool.generate_normals()
    mesh_builder.commit(mesh)
```

Remember they are stored as triangle fans. They all share the first vertex (`data[1]`). So, in `4 0 1 2 3` the triangles share the vertex stored in the array at position `0`.

We can iterate over `data` to get the second vertex. Which means this time we need to skip two elements (the `4` and `0`), hence the `2` in `range(2, data.size() - 1)`.

Finally the third vertex is always the next one after the second. Which also means we cannot iterate until the end, hence the `- 1` in `range(2, data.size() - 1)`.

---

Afterwards, you can then set the `mesh` to a `MeshIntance`.